# JavaFX 8 - Application Icon will only sometimes appear

Tags: java, javafx, jruby, javafx-8, jrubyfx

I'm adding my application icon with `stage.getIcons().add(new Image("path"))` and the icon will appear sometimes, so I know that the program can find the resource and I'm calling the right methods, but the icon won't appear every time. From what I can tell from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280398/image-will-only-load-sometimes) this is probably because swing (which I believe JavaFX uses) loads images in a separate thread. If this is the problem, how can I ensure that loading and adding the icon finishes before I call stage.show()? If this is not the problem, what is going on here and what am I doing wrong? I'm using JRuby so your answer can include Ruby libs if they're applicable. A purely Java answer is fine too.

Comment: By making the icon add the very first line in my start method, I was able to get it working all the time. This is only, presumably, because I had enough methods between `stage.getIcons().add` and `stage.show()` that gave time for the image to load. Its not really a solution.

Comment: This question has some incorrect assumptions.  JavaFX 8 does not use Swing.  A JavaFX Image is loaded synchronously, not asynchronously (unless you explicitly set a [background loading flag in the Image constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-) - which you don't do).  I cannot reproduce your issue using a pure Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that the program process that loads the image does did not finish loading before you are showing it. You can add a `wait()` function after your icon addition. Or you can execute another function in between your `add(new Image("pokemon.png"))` and your `primaryStage.show()` this will ensure that your image load will finish before you show the stage.